# Need assistance troubleshooting Logical Volume mount failure

Tags: mount, lvm, ubuntu-16.04

I am experimenting with LVM and setting up a new webserver on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I am unable to mount my logical volumes.

The webserver has two physical volumes. I used the installation program to set up the first volume /dev/sda, and installed the operating system. Now I am trying to configure the second device and mount it.

I used pvcreate, vgcreate and lvcreate to create the following (output from lvscan):

```
ACTIVE '/dev/medface-vg2/logs' [100.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE '/dev/medface-vg2/webapp' [1.90 GiB] inherit
```

Each of these partitions is visible on the filesystem at /dev/medface-vg2/logs and /dev/medface-vg2/webapp.

I then created /var/www as a mount point using mkdir. The other mount point was already created on system setup at /var/log.

Using the commands, `sudo mount /dev/medface-vg2/logs /var/log` and `sudo mount /dev/medface-vg2/webapp /var/www`, should mount my logical volumes to the file structure for use, but instead I see the following message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on [lv reference here] missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.
```

When I run `dmesg | tail` I see the following:

```
[ 1251.731372] sdb: sdb1
[ 1251.732037] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 1251.732225] sdb: sdb1
[ 1326.450014] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
```

This message is repeated with the initial number, which I presume to by a type of time stamp incrementing.

I have seen references to gdisk, but my system does not hav gdisk installed, so I am thinking that there must be another helper program that can assist.

I have access to fdisk, but I am thinking that fdisk might not work with the lvm volumes. Perhaps this is a misconseption, because I used fdisk to prep the physical drives before using lvm, I visualize fdisk operating at a lower level than lvm and therefore unable to understand the lvm constructs.

How do I mount these oversized volumes?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will answer the question now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit the /etc/fstab file, I tried identifying the volume file system types and realized that I never created the file system. Mount was trying to tell me that I never created the file system.

I used `mkfs` to create `ext4` file systems on each logical volume. I then re-ran the mount commands, and everything worked as expected. There were no more errors!

So, the answer to my problem is:

Don't forget to create the file systems using `mkfs` before mounting the logical volumes.